# Set array elements (string) as variable name in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, variables

I have the following array, that I use to later write the header on an Excel file.

```
fields = ["fileName", "type", "id"]
```

And then I have the following code that reads values from an XML:

```
filename = xml.xpath('//path/filename').text
type = xml.xpath('//path/type').text
id = xml.xpath('//path/id').text
```

The I iterate the initial array (fields) in order to set the Excel cells to the values extracted in the previous step:

```
row = 2
c = 1
fields.each do |content|
  ws.Cells(row,c).Value = content
  c = c + 1
```

I'm trying to have the array's (`fields`) contents to variable names instead of strings in order to be able to reuse the head fields.

Can anyone recommend a way of making it possible?

Comment: Any time you find yourself wanting to look up local variables using code, or create local variables using code, you should realize that this is "code smell" and you should instead be using a collection like a hash or an array, or a structured object.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like you need to use a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) to associate field names to the values you extracted:

```
fields = {
  "fileName" => xml.xpath('//path/filename').text,
  "type" => xml.xpath('//path/type').text,
  "id" => xml.xpath('//path/id').text
}

row=2
c=1
fields.each do |key,value|
  ws.Cells(row,c).Value = value
  c=c+1
end
```

Comment: Even better: `values={}; fields.each{ |name| values[name]=xml.at_xpath("//path/#{name}").text }`

Comment: @Phrogz well, I thought about that, but I assumed fileName vs. filename was not a typo.

Comment: It is a typo. Thanks for your comments... I'm pretty new to Ruby so I would try what you are proposing.